# Lua setfenv to exclude or include some methods

Tags: methods, lua, sandbox, garrys-mod

What I want to achieve is that Player:SetDeaths is not accessible while Player:Deaths will be accessible.

```
local newgt = {print = print, player = LocalPlayer()}
setmetatable(newgt, {})
setfenv(1, newgt)
print(player:Deaths())
```

In the example above I can access ALL methods from LocalPlayer() but I want to limit this to the methods of my choice

```
local newgt = {print = print, playerdeaths = LocalPlayer():Deaths()}
setmetatable(newgt, {})
setfenv(1, newgt)
print(playerdeaths)
```

This was the only way I could find, but it looks annoying.

Comment: Use proxy table for `player`

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: [Link](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html)